# Receiving Two Objects in req.body

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am receiving a POST request from an Unity app in x-form-encoded format into my NodeJs web-server .

I use `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))` , to parse the content . But the `req.body` returns two objects , problem is that I cannot access the property of an individual property since they are neither wrapped in an array or object .

On `console.log(req.body)`

I get the following result

```
{ sessionId: '5ujgp6vwk1pivth4', gameId: '1', level: '0', score: '0' }            

{ sessionId: '5ujgp6vwk1pivth4', gameId: '2', level: '0', score: '0' }
```

I want to know which type of datatype is this and how will I be able to access a particular property , suppose if I do 
`console.log(req.body.sessionId)` , I get

```
5ujgp6vwk1pivth4

5ujgp6vwk1pivth4
```

Even if I try to push it into an array I still get the same result .

I am trying to fetch these objects into an array so that it will be easier for me to access them .

The script for the Express routes :

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const hbs = require('hbs')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const viewsRouter = require('./routers/views')
const apiRouter = require('./routers/api')
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
require ('./db/mongoose')

const app = express()
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}))
app.use(cookieParser())
const publicDirectoryPath = path.join(__dirname,'../public')
app.use(express.static(publicDirectoryPath))
const viewsPath = path.join(__dirname,'../templates/views')
const partialsPath = path.join(__dirname,'../templates/partials')

hbs.registerPartials(partialsPath)
hbs.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
if(v1 === v2) {
return options.fn(this);
}
return options.inverse(this);
});
hbs.registerHelper("math", function(lvalue, operator, rvalue, options) {
lvalue = parseFloat(lvalue);
rvalue = parseFloat(rvalue);

return {
  "+": lvalue + rvalue,
  "-": lvalue - rvalue,
  "*": lvalue * rvalue,
  "/": lvalue / rvalue,
  "%": lvalue % rvalue
  }[operator];
  });
app.use(viewsRouter)
app.use(apiRouter)
// For any of the un-handled routes
app.get('*',(req,res)=>{
res.render('error')
})

//Setting up the CORS functionality in Express for Making AJAX calls
app.use(function(req, res, next) {

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

next();

});

app.set('views',viewsPath)
app.set('view engine','hbs')


app.listen(80,()=>{
console.log('Server Started on Port 80')
})
```

The Route responsible for the particular POST is

```
apiRouter.post('/api/updateScore/',async(req,res)=>{ 
console.log(req.body)
})
```

The client script is :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;
using System.Text;

public class ScoreSender : MonoBehaviour {

public Authentication authentication;
public  static readonly string scoreUrl = "https://eyenet.pythonanywhere.com/scores/";
public static ScoreSender instance;
public string Address = "127.0.0.1:8000";
// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    instance = this;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}

public void sendScore(int gameId, int level)
{

}

public void sendScore(string gameId, int level, int score)
{
    string loginURL = Address+ "/api/updateScore/";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField( "sessionId", authentication.session );
    Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
    byte[] rawData = form.data;

    WWW www = new WWW(loginURL, rawData, headers);

}
    // StartCoroutine(WaitForRequest(www));



public void saveScore(string gameId, int nextlevel, int score)
{

    // get session id
    string sessionCode = authentication.session;

    // get score array
    int noOfGames = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalGames",0);

    // get or create score, level, nextlevel arrays
    int gid = int.Parse(gameId);


    //
    int[] scoreArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionCode+"scores",0,noOfGames+1);
    int[] nextLevelsArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionCode+"nextLevels",0,noOfGames+1);

    nextLevelsArray[gid] = nextlevel;
    scoreArray[gid] = score;

    PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray(sessionCode+"scores",scoreArray);
    PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray(sessionCode+"nextLevels",nextLevelsArray);

    PlayerPrefsX.SetIntArray("gameLevels",nextLevelsArray);
    Debug.Log("saved score and nextLevels offline");
}

//for sending score to the cloud


public void uploadScore()
{
    //testing
    //StartCoroutine(scoreSend(authentication.session,"1",45,34));
    syncScore(authentication.session);

}


//for online sessions only
void syncScore(string sessionId)
{
    Debug.Log("We are syncing the score for this session");

    int noOfGames = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalGames",0);
    int[] currentGamePlays = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"currentGamePlays",0,noOfGames);
    int[] scoreArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"scores",0,noOfGames+1);
    int[] nextLevelsArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"nextLevels",0,noOfGames+1);


    for(int i=0;i<noOfGames+1;i++)
    {
        if(currentGamePlays[i]==1)  //if the game is played in this session
        {
            StartCoroutine( scoreSend(sessionId,""+i,nextLevelsArray[i],scoreArray[i]));
            Debug.Log("score:"+scoreArray[i]);
            Debug.Log("level:"+nextLevelsArray[i]);
        }
    }
}


public int noOfScores=0;

public void syncOfflineScore(int num,string actualId)
{
    string sessionId = "offlineSession"+num;

    int noOfGames = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("totalGames",0);
    int[] currentGamePlays = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"currentGamePlays",0,noOfGames+1);
    int[] scoreArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"scores",0,noOfGames+1);
    int[] nextLevelsArray = PlayerPrefsX.GetIntArray(sessionId+"nextLevels",0,noOfGames+1);


    for(int i=0;i<noOfGames+1;i++)
    {
        if(currentGamePlays[i]==1)  //if the game is played in this session
        {
            noOfScores++;
        }
    }


    for(int i=0;i<noOfGames+1;i++)
    {
        if(currentGamePlays[i]==1)  //if the game is played in this session
        {
            StartCoroutine( offlineScoreSend(actualId,""+i,nextLevelsArray[i],scoreArray[i]));
            Debug.Log("score:"+scoreArray[i]);
            Debug.Log("level:"+nextLevelsArray[i]);
        }
    }


}







//working fine
IEnumerator scoreSend(string sessionId,string gameId,int nextlevel, int score)
{
    string scoreUrl = authentication.Address+ "/api/updateScore/";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField( "sessionId", sessionId );
    form.AddField( "gameId", gameId );
    form.AddField( "level", nextlevel);
    form.AddField( "score", score);

    Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
    //Dictionary<string, string> headers = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    //headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    byte[] rawData = form.data;

    WWW www = new WWW(scoreUrl, rawData, headers);
    WWW data =www;

    yield return data;
    if(data.error!=null)
    {
        Debug.Log (data.error); 

        if(data.error == "Cannot connect to destination host")
        {

        }

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(data.text);
        ServerResponse res = JsonUtility.FromJson<ServerResponse>(data.text);
        if(res.status==0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Updated score");

        }   
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Got an error");
        }
    }
}


//test it
IEnumerator offlineScoreSend(string sessionId,string gameId,int nextlevel, int score)
{
    string scoreUrl = authentication.Address+ "/api/updateScore/";

    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();

    form.AddField( "sessionId", sessionId );
    form.AddField( "gameId", gameId );
    form.AddField( "level", nextlevel);
    form.AddField( "score", score);

    Dictionary<string, string> headers = form.headers;
    byte[] rawData = form.data;

    WWW www = new WWW(scoreUrl, rawData, headers);
    WWW data =www;

    yield return data;
    if(data.error!=null)
    {
        Debug.Log (data.error); 

        if(data.error == "Cannot connect to destination host")
        {

        }

    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log(data.text);
        ServerResponse res = JsonUtility.FromJson<ServerResponse>(data.text);
        if(res.status==0)
        {
            Debug.Log("Updated score");
            noOfScores--;
            if(noOfScores==0)
            {
                authentication.syncOfflineSessionsDataComplete();
            }
        }   
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("Got an error");
        }
    }
}





}
```

Comment: What you get if you do `console.log(req)` share that please

Comment: 1. Your unity app sends 2 requests separately, to prove it use morgan https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan#expressconnect  2. `req.body` is an object and `req.body.sessionId` is a string. 3. if `req.body` would be an array it would put square brackets around these 2 objects. 4. to understand what is req.body contents: `console.log(typeof req.body); console.log(req.body); console.log(typeof req.body.sessionId); console.log(req.body.sessionId);`

Comment: Is it not an object of objects and therefore you could use `Object.entries` to iterate?

Comment: @muasif80 The data is too lrge to comment, I have shared it on pastebin , please have a look at it 
[link](https://pastebin.com/wFcxuUHN)

Comment: Any chance you've accidentally installed the handler for that route (/api/updateScore/) twice? That would explain you seeing two things printed out every time you use console.log().

Comment: @num8er Thanks for the help, it really is two independent post requests being sent by the client due to which the route handler are running twice , I was just being confused with the way it printed on console.log(), it was actually the route handler running twice , due to which the req.body was also being logged twice .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, what is happening is different than what you think is happening, and there isn't enough information here to figure out what is actually going on.  You say that req.body is returning two objects, but that they are not wrapped in an array or another object, which is fundamentally impossible.

Given the information available, my best guess is that the bodyParser is working exactly as it should, but that whatever client application you are using to send requests is sending two requests where you think it's only sending one, so when you log it you are seeing two objects and assuming they came from a single call to `console.log` which doesn't appear to be the case.

To confirm that, I would probably stick something like this into the bottom of the file, and then use this to log instead of using `console.log` directly.  This will demonstrate that it's two different log entries coming from two different invocations of the route.

```
let counter = 0;
function logWithCounter( ...msg ) {
  console.log( counter++, ...msg );
}
```

Comment: After running the above snippet I get :

0 { sessionId: '5ujgph9ck1pkbz9a', gameId: '1', level: '0', score: '0' }

0 { sessionId: '5ujgph9ck1pkbz9a', gameId: '2', level: '0', score: '0' }

The counter does not increment

Comment: But the counter does get logged twice, which shows that it's definitely two different calls and not that you somehow have two different objects in the body, but like I said there isn't enough information to tell what is actually going on.  If you post the code you are having trouble with you may get a better response.

Comment: Thanks @Jason Kohles  Everything works perfectly fine it's just that there are two POST requests to the same route handler and the route handler executes twice which produces the two console logs, I was just confused with the way it appeared due to the console.log() , my bad .